# Cannot see additionally added .swift files when installed the pod locally or remotely in iOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I created a pod using `pod lib create 'mypodname'`. and below is the 
default structure given from **Xcode**.

[image]

- Most of the tutorials, I can see folder called `Classes` inside `MyFirtTestPod` folder. but in here we don't have it.
- In other hand, I can add new `.swift` files, but after installed the pod using local path to another project or,  after installed remotely after `truncated` can only see `ReplaceMe.swift` as a `.swift` file. **I tried with deleting `RepalceMe.swift` file and adding new `.swift` files. but didn't work. the only thing I can do is rename `ReplaceMe.swift`. I can see those files in `github` but not in the installed pod**

this my `.podspec` file and the file structure

[image]

Comment: post your podspec here

Comment: @Bannings added the podspec here

Comment: @JonasSchafft what do you mean. in here I'm creating a pod , not using pod

Comment: 404: https://github.com/biljobs/testpod

Comment: Delete `Classes` part of path in `s.source_files` in podspec.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your post, you can't see new `.swift` files in your installed pod, correct?

In your newly created `.podspec` file, you can see Cocoapod's comment about the Source Code:

```
  # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  CocoaPods is smart about how it includes source code. For source files
  #  giving a folder will include any swift, h, m, mm, c & cpp files.
  #  For header files it will include any header in the folder.
  #  Not including the public_header_files will make all headers public.
  #
```

Almost all (except `Bolts`) frameworks in Cocoapod I use have no folders. So when you browse the Pods > AFramework, you can already see its classes.

Here is the simplest `.podspec` code for the source code and resources. Try it. As you can see, I'm giving the source code section my path from the very root folder of my pod. `GPKit/**/*.{swift}` as well as my resources. I've had the same problem with yours in the past but for the resources (e.g. `.xib`) and not for the `.swift` files.

```
 # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  CocoaPods is smart about how it includes source code. For source files
  #  giving a folder will include any swift, h, m, mm, c & cpp files.
  #  For header files it will include any header in the folder.
  #  Not including the public_header_files will make all headers public.
  #

  s.source_files = "GPKit", "GPKit/**/*.{swift}"


  # ――― Resources ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  A list of resources included with the Pod. These are copied into the
  #  target bundle with a build phase script. Anything else will be cleaned.
  #  You can preserve files from being cleaned, please don't preserve
  #  non-essential files like tests, examples and documentation.
  #

  # s.resource  = "icon.png"
  # s.resources = "Resources/*.png"

  s.resources = "GPKit/**/*.{xib}"


  # s.preserve_paths = "FilesToSave", "MoreFilesToSave"

  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '3' }
```